# restoreCompletedTransactions broken?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Is restoreCompletedTransactions broken in SDK 4.3 ?

I am trying to restore my auto-renewable subscription. It is not resulting in callback to updatedTransactions. Here is my code.

```
 {
 ....
 [appDelegate.inapp loadStore];

 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]  restoreCompletedTransactions];
 ....
 }
```

Expecting callback to updatedTransactions, but do not receive it.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
     NSLog(@"IN updatedTransactions,  transaction.transactionState");

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            ...
            ...
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"IN updatedTransactions,  SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

But I do receive call to this at the end.

```
-(void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
}
```

Comment: Is this fixed? I'm having the same problem and I can't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 26):

This can still(1) happen if you're testing in the Sandbox environment and your **Test User is broken**. Create a new Test User in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), and try again.

It's not entirely clear what makes Test Users go bad; from what I gather, using them once in a non-sandbox environment can do this, but there may be other reasons as well.

(1) Xcode 4.3.1, iOS SDK 5.1

Comment: I have experienced a number of 'broken Test users' (having created over 400 sandbox text users).  I cannot see what seems to break them, but I have not yet used the test users to purchase a 'prod' app.

Comment: Bang on, thanks.  Those test users are delicate - it's become my testing flow to be creating incremental test users during testing.

Comment: Yikes! My test user had "gone bad" too...It's a very small sample, but mine seemed to go bad after my app's going through Apple's review...possibly related?

Comment: Wow - here is another victim of a "bad" test user. I suspect if you try and set the account in the system preferences, and go on to verify it as an actual account (credit cards, etc.) that will make it go bad.

Comment: How can I identify if my test user is broken?

Comment: @RahulMathur I never found a reliable way to test that.

Comment: Even 8 years later after the original answer a similar issue happened on my case too. When I restored a purchase with a sandbox user, StoreKit was not responding to any SKProductRequest calls. (The restore was successful, but I couldn't get any other product responses.) Rebooting the device was a temporary solution, but creating a new user fixed the issue completely.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure to add observer before using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]  restoreCompletedTransactions];`

Your code should be something like:

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`

Answer (score 4):

Products **Consumable** cannot be restored.

Products **Non-Consumable** can be restored.

Check if your products are type **Non-Consumable**.

Comment: But there is no `SKProduct` parameter in this method, `SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this but its very odd. On my testing device im getting bugged by iTunes to log in to multiple test user accounts. I usually just hit cancel and test my restore with the account that I want to restore. This time I decided to enter the password for these other annoying login boxes. It worked and next time I relaunched my app and hit restore it did not bug me to log in to the other test accounts, just the one I was testing. I proceeded with the restore and it did restore the items I wanted to see.

Id say were experinecing stupid sandbox issues and also we know apple has changed in app purchasing in general. Keep playing around with it, you'll get it to work out.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Apple got back to my ticket. It is a bug with 4.3.1. Looks like they have fixed it now.

Comment: still facing the same problem in iOS 5.0

Comment: still facing the same problem on iOS 6 and iOS 7. C'mon Apple.

Comment: Entering the password for all test users worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the updatedTransactions callback if you are getting paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished.  The "queue" has a list of your transactions and you can loop thru those.

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) 
        if ([myItem.productID isEqualToString:transaction.payment.productIdentifier])
            myItem.purchased = YES;
}
```

Comment: This is from Apple documentation. "This method is called after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue. Your application is not required to do anything in this method.". I also feel this is a bug in iOS, but i am facing it in iOS 5.0 so not sure why the comment in above answer by okgo saying that it is fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your build number in Xcode does not have a space in it.  For example "1.0 Beta".  With a space updatedTransactions will not be called.  Also receipt verification can fail.

Answer (score 0):

Two additional points which weren't mentioned here:

1. If you are using **Firebase** make sure you add an observer before you initialize Firebase, https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=ios
2. Make sure that you call **finishTransaction** method while handling the purchase. You won't be able to restore not completed transactions.