# SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions: no transaction restored

Tags: ios, transactions, storekit

I can't receive any transactions in my `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` delegate Method. Only the delegate method `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` gets hit by the debugger. When i try to retreive the transaction array, i get an empty array.

First of all, i buy a non-renewing product. After successfully purchaseing and verifying it from the server, it will be removed from the payment queue. Than at startup, i call the paymentqueues `restoreCompletedTransactions` method. As expected the Storekit asks me for the password (from the sandbox-user) which i enter. But the update Method won't get cought. Only the finish Method gets caught and as discribed, the transactions are empty.

What am i doing wrong? Is it my fault, or is it apples [restoreCompletedTransactions broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628710/restorecompletedtransactions-broken)?

Thanks and BR
Nic

Comment: If I'm correct you have to keep track of transaction receipts on your own server.

Comment: I do. But whenever i call the restoreCompletedTransactions method, it should restore all purchases (so the In-App Purchase Programming Guide)

Comment: Consumable products shouldn't get restored, they're one-time-use. Test it with a non-consumable.

Comment: I have this same problem with non-consumables.

Comment: @D Carney: Non-consumables should get restored. Did it appear suddenly or is it already gone? I also had a problem, with restoring auto renewing subscriptions, but it turned out to be an apple sandbox problem. @JoePasq: Thank you for the answer, it really helped me progress with the problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for letting you wait for such a long time!

The problem is that in Apples [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http:///epaper_ipad_iphone/12-04-17/KLZE_STMK_0417_001_0_2012.pdf) it clearly says, that i cannot take non-renewing subscriptions to be restored. I'll have to store the purchases on my own and implement an own restore functionality.

What i did was including some identifiers in the product name, that tell me, what kind of product it is. (Its one method to store information of the product without using my own server) So my Products name is e.g. com.mycompany.iphone.non_renewing_30d (This product is really configured as a non renewing product)

So when the user makes a purchase, i store this information in the iDevice's CoreData Database. I also include my expire functionality, because i have the purchase date and the products expire date (30d).

When the time expires, the user sees a message dialog which tells to make a new purchase. I really don't like apples implementation of non-renewing subscriptions because it tells the user, that he/she already bought the product and asks them to repurchase, but i had to deal with that.

I really suggest to store the purchase information on the iOS Device, because you don't need to create your own user recognize functionality (e.g. a userId or email adress), since Apple turned off the UDID uniqueness.

Comment: But when the user uninstalls the app, they lose their purchase. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Thats correct! You need to store it on your own server. To store the data for a specific user, you also need to create your own account/login system. BR