# restoreCompletedTransactions askign morethan one password

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i am doing one application.In that i implemented auto renewal subscription.And i tested the app in sandbox mode with different test accounts.when i delete the application from device and reinstall,i am calling the restoreCompletedTransactions method like below

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

But on that time,i am getting the password required alert for so many test account(Whatever i used previously) and didn't get the response from apple.How to get the response from apple.

Comment: try it by creating new test user account.

Comment: Then also not getting the response from apple

Comment: are you getting any specific error. what is the `transactionstate` you're getting in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`

Comment: No,That delegate also not firing.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628710/restorecompletedtransactions-broken

Comment: I did the same thing,But no use at all.

Comment: If i use the single account also,didn't get the reply from apple

Comment: restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError method also not firing.And i am testing in ios 7 ipad mini device with development certificate using xcode 5.0.2

Comment: Check any of your profile mismatches in `Xcode build settings` or check your `in-app purchase` settings in `itunesconnect`

Comment: I removed the common provisioning profiles from xcode and checked the in app purchase settings.Everything is fine.But not getting the response from apple